# Group arrays if id is the same in angularjs

Tags: php, json, angularjs, laravel

I have an array that I'm spitting out into a json and it looks like this:

```
 {
 id: 207
 order_id: 9325
 other_id: 3332
 }
 {
 id: 207
 order_id: 4444
 other_id: 33233
 }
 {
 id: 437
 order_id: 9325
 other_id: 22233
 }
```

If the id is the same, I want it to look like this:

```
 id: 207
     {
       order_id: 9325
       other_id: 3332
     },
     {
       order_id: 4444
       other_id: 33233
     }
```

etc..

So far my backend code that spits out the json looks like this:

```
    foreach($others as $other)
    {

        if(!empty($other->table_one))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            $checks[] = array('id' => $other->id, 'order_id' => $other->order_id, 'other_id' => $other->other_id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another level in your array so you can use the `$other->id` as the array key, and add arrays under it containing the `order_id` and `other_id`. Try this instead:

```
foreach($others as $other) {
    if(!empty($other->table_one)) {
        continue;

    // Create a blank array before trying to use it
    if(!array_key_exists($other->id, $checks))
        $checks[$other->id] = array();

    // Add this entry to your array
    $checks[$other->id][] = array(
        'order_id' => $other->order_id,
        'other_id' => $other->other_id
    );
}
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/187431) (PHP output), and if you `json_encode()` it:

```
{
    "207": [
        {
            "order_id": 9325,
            "other_id": 3332
        },
        {
            "order_id": 4444,
            "other_id": 33233
        }
    ],
    "437": [
        {
            "order_id": 9325,
            "other_id": 22233
        }
    ]
}
```